# Refresh ListView when returned to activity on android

Tags: android

I am currently developing an android app. The app has 2 activities. Activity 1 is a ListActivity. ListActivity calls a standard Activity. When the 2nd activity is finished, I use the finish() method to close the activitity which returns to the ListActivity. I need the ListActivity to now refresh with the new dat

Answer (score 2):

You should just call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter when you return back to your activity.

The [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html) states:

> void notifyDataSetChanged()
>
> Notifies the attached View that the
> underlying data has been changed and
> it should refresh itself.

Comment: I didn't want to post an answer since yours seems to be better but wouldn't the return to the first activity trigger an on resume event ?

Comment: It would... so he could invoke `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the ArrayAdapter in that method.

Comment: @Jason, yes but I don't think the adapter would update. I think you do indeed need to notify.

Comment: My mistake, I thought the question was to find where to trigger the refresh not how to trigger it :$

Answer (score 1):

Have you packaged the data into and intent? For that matter did you startActivityForResult()? If so the you would take the data out of the intent by overriding the onActivityResult(...) method and add the data to what ever you need to do. Then like sahhhm said notifyDataSetChanged().

~Aedon

Answer (score 0):

You need reload the info in the ListView...

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mAdapter= new mYCustomAdapter(mActivity.this, valuesReloaded);
            mList.setAdapter(mAdapter); 

           mAdapter.myMethodThatNotifyChange();  

}
```

where:
valuesReloaded is the new Array with the new Values.
mAdapter is a Custom Adapter
myMethodThatNotifyChange  is a method in the Class MyCustomAdapter where you must call notifyDataSetChanged() , ( in a custom adapter can only call from the class adapter)

```
class myCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
...
...
myMethodThatNotifyChange{
notifyDataSetChanged();
}
...
...
}
```

Or finish the actual activity, and reload with a new intent

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

Intent mIntet = new Intent(mlistViewPersons.this , mlistViewPersons.class)
startActivity(mIntent);
finish();

}
```